# CkoSSHTunnel keyboard-interactive?

Tags: ssh, chilkat

[CkoSSH](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/objcCkoSshRef.html#method59) has a few methods for performing keyboard-interactive ssh logins. Specifically I mean `StartKeyboardAuth` and `ContinueKeyboardAuth`. I'm wondering if its possible to use these methods somehow through [CkoSSHTunnel](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/objcCkoSshTunnelRef.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added these methods to CkoSshTunnel.  Here are pre-release downloads for v9.5.0.78

(MacOSX) https://chilkatdownload.com/prerelease/chilkat-9.5.0-macosx-objc-1420.zip

(iOS v9 and above)  https://chilkatdownload.com/prerelease/chilkat-9.5.0-ios9-1421.zip